# Javascript wait for function (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have problem with my function.

There is:

```
function set_session(session_name, hodonota) {
    var link = '/run/set_session.html?what=' + session_name + '&val=' + hodonota;
    $("#test").load(link, function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = 'Error';
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

I have other function for check data:

```
function make() {
    var error = false;
    var a = $("#val").val();

    if (a != '') {
        set_session('a', a);
    } else {
        error = true;
    }

    if (error == false) {
        window.location.href = "/sended.php";
    }
}
```

If i try make and value if '', all is ok, but if value != '', windows.location start before set_session is completed. Set session alert 'Error' :(

Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: Why not handle it inside the `complete` callback function of the `load`?

Comment: Hello Ben, how can I edit function please ? I don't know, how it works.

Comment: I agree. Your best option is to do `[...].load([...]).complete(function() { make(); });` instead of how you call make now.

Comment: Please tell me you're not setting server-side session variable from client-side script

Comment: Please see my answer. That having been said, @YuriyGalanter makes a valid point. If you have an AJAX script in your site that allows the manipulation of session variables, this could represent a **serious** security issue!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're redirecting the user, you can just hook the redirect into the `success` callback function of your `load()` function. Your whole code should look something like this:

```
function make() 
{
    var error = false,
        a = $.trim($("#val").val());

    if(a != '')
    {
        var link = '/run/set_session.html?what=a&val=' + a;
        $("#test").load(link, function (response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = 'Error';
                alert(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.href = '/sended.php';
            }
        });
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I made a few tweaks to your code as well. Oh, and by the way the past participle of 'send' is 'sent', not 'sended'.

Please also be aware that @YuriyGalanter makes a valid point. If you have an AJAX script in your site that allows the manipulation of session variables, this could represent a **serious** security issue!

Comment: Thnak you BenM. But, how can i make this, if I need more set function ?
http://pastebin.com/1tWMqCE9

Comment: In a similar vain, just handle the two URL parameters as variables. You'd probably be better passing them as an object too, rather than adding them to the string.

Comment: tended to downvote for lack of readability (even the author had better readability with 2 methods) and you changed functionality by adding `"return false"`.

Comment: BenM can you please edit function for more set_session and when is all complete, go url ? http://pastebin.com/1tWMqCE9
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

How is this? Thanks to @11684 for the `complete()`-syntax.

```
function make() {

    var val = $("#val").val();

    if (val != '') {
        set_session('a', val, toSendPage);
    }
}

function set_session( session_name, hodonota, callback ) {

    var link = '/run/set_session.html?what=' + session_name + '&val=' + hodonota;

    $("#test").load(link, function (response, status, xhr) {

        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = 'Error';
            alert(msg);
        }

    }).complete( callback );
}

function toSentPage() {
    window.location.href = "/sended.php";
}
```

And yes it's 'sent' not 'sended'.

Comment: does that `complete` syntax work?  According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/), `#load` returns a jQuery object, not a promise/jqXHR.  And besides this, jQuery promises would use done/always, not complete.

Comment: @numbers1311407 i have no idea, i took it from the comments in the post, assuming he knew what he wrote.

Comment: You know what they say about assuming :-P

Comment: Assumption is the only certaincy in life? xD Kidding, I have to agree with you.